# How to connect PostgreSQL database in JavaScript in right way and check the connection?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to connect my PostgreSQL database using JavaScript, but for some reasons i am not able to and getting error messages as below. Could you please advise what is the error and how i can fix it to be able to show the table content

```js
const {Client} = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    user: "postgres",
    password: "xxxxx",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database: "simoo"
})

client.connect()
.then(() => client.query("select * from Countries"))
.then(results => console.table(results.rows))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
.finally(() => client.end())
```

when I am using command "npm test" to check if I can get the raw in table, I get this error message:

```js
PS D:\beravaa\beravanode> npm test

> beravanode@1.0.0 test
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

"Error: no test specified"
```

I also tried this command "node index.js" to check the connection and get the table data, but I get this error message which telling that table is not exist which of course not correct as I have this table already:

```js
error: relation "countries" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\beravaa\beravanode\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\beravaa\beravanode\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\beravaa\beravanode\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\beravaa\beravanode\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 108,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '15',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '1384',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable'
}
```

Comment: From someone with your status I wouldn't expect this comment, but https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask from where? how, what did you try and what did you expect?

Comment: I think you need to show schema of postgresql's also in credentials